# добавление элемента рядом при делегировании событий

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Значится вот сама разметка к которой я применяю делегирование

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <a> Заголовок 1 </a> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a> Заголовок 2 </a> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a> Заголовок 3 </a> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a> Заголовок 4 </a> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Смысл в том, чтобы делегирование срабатывало на все иконки, которые в списке, но при этом, при клике в localStorage Добавлялся бы текст который внутри тега "а". 
Не понял я как добавить innerHTML элемента соседнего, по которому был совершен клик.

Этот код добавляет текст собственно при самом клике на текст элемента.

```js
  list.addEventListener('click', event => { 
    let title = event.target.innerHTML,
        item = event.target,
        index = bookmarks.indexOf(title);

    if (!title) return;

    if (index == -1) {
      bookmarks.push(title);
      item.classList.add('bookmark')
    } else {
      bookmarks.splice(index, 1);
      item.classList.remove('bookmark')
    }

    localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  });
```

Comment: "элемента соседнего, по которому был совершен клик." - что это значит?

Comment: @Igor Ну значит, что если я кликаю на <i> - в LocalStorage Должен добавляться текст из <a> . Ну то есть они соседние.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
title = event.target.closest(".list__item").querySelector("a").innerHTML,
```